# Difference between Websphere Application Server profiles and WAS editions

Tags: java, websphere

I am currently trying to build a Websphere Cluster , however the names of the Websphere Application server editions ( like Base , Developers , Network deployment etc ) and the concept of Profiles has got me confused .

1. Is there a difference in the code base within the various Websphere server editions like Base , Express , Network Deployment etc ?
2. Is the Network Deployment version the only one that supports Clustering ?
3. If I build a dmgr profile on any of the other versions ( like WAS for developers etc )  can I get clustering to work ?
4. Is using Installation Manager the only way of installing WAS 8.5 Network Deployment edition on Linux ? I read in this blog http://ianrobinson.blogspot.in/ that there is another simpler way , however I am not sure if this is meant for installing the Network Deployment edition  .
5. How is the WAS developer's version different from the Network Deployment version ?

Comment: I know that this is not a helpful comment, but run away from heavy containers such as websphere, they sound amazing but they are a nightmare.

Comment: :) ... good one ... but I still need to know :)

Answer (score 4):

***1. Is there a difference in the code base within the various WebSphere server editions like Base , Express , Network Deployment etc ?***

In the context of Java EE and programming API - there is no difference - same code base. There is of course difference in licensing and cost. ND in addition has components required to support clustering and distributed installations (like deployment manager, secure proxy or edge components). There is also Intelligent Management (previously known as WebSphere Virtual Enterprise) integrated in ND since 8.5. [Express limitation](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/appserv-wasexp) is currently a maximum of 480 processor value units. It is limited to a 32-bit application server implementation. But it is changing from version to version, so you should always check the web site for actual data.

In addition since WAS v8.5 there is new lightweight, modular, Java EE 6 web profile certified WebSphere Liberty Edition. It is based on same code packaged as OSGi modules, so you can compose server from only required components. It also already supports some of Java EE 7 features. For latest info - check [wasdev.net](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/)

***2. Is the Network Deployment version the only one that supports Clustering ?***

If you are thinking of centralized management, and deployment then yes, it is only available in the ND.

However other editions support something called *[simple load balancing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/twsv_configsimplelb.html?lang=en)*.

> Simple load balancing distributes HTTP requests across multiple IBM®
>   WebSphere® Application Server instances. You can configure simple load
>   balancing to provide failover of an application state that is
>   maintained in an HTTP session.

In this case each of server instances is separately maintained and administered, and you have to manually install same application in each. This is kind of same server farm approach. Session can be shared across servers using database.

Similar lightweight clustering is also possible with [WebSphere Liberty collectives](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.iseries.doc/ae/cwlp_collective_arch.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F2-3-11-0-2-6-0&lang=en).

***3. If I build a dmgr profile on any of the other versions (like WAS for developers etc) can I get clustering to work?***

There is no dmgr profile in other versions that ND. You could federate that instance to the dmgr for management. Even, if you would be able to create cluster it will be a violation of license.

***4. Is using Installation Manager the only way of installing WAS 8.5 Network Deployment edition on Linux?***

In general - yes.
However:

- each edition can be installed silently, if you don't have X-Windows
- Hypervisor Edition comes in a preinstalled image, which you just deploy as virtual machine and run configuration scripts, so no installation with IM.

WebSphere Liberty can be installed using Installation Manager or downloaded as archive, and extracted.

***5. How is the WAS developer's version different from the Network Deployment version ?***
Developers edition is free for development, not licensed for production usage. Doesn't support clustering - see ad 1).

Answer (score 2):

1. No difference but features differs and has limitations. For example, Express is 32 bit only and the maximum PVU is capped. Base has no clustering.
2. Yes
3. You can't cluster WAS Express and WAS Base although you can control them with a Dmgr by making them part of a cell. This is called federating a node.
4. Not sure about this one but I would think there is a console installer.
5. WAS Developper is intended to give the same features as a production environment for free but you must use it only for development on a local desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Base does have clustering just not memory-to-memory (only via database persistence).

You however need to merge plugin configurations
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftwsv_configsimplelb.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe Base version has database session persistence clustering with some limitation. Feel free to correct me ;-)

You can add cache clustering with frameworks like infinispan

Comment: For caching I'd strongly suggest provided in WAS 8.5.5 WebSphere Extreme Scale, which integrates much better than third party Infinispan